# How to render two elements of an array in a single div / row using Array map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The idea is to take 2 elements from the array `foods` and insert them in a single div while the `foods.map` is running.

Here is the code I've been working on:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

import { Container } from './styles';

const foods = [
  'batata-palha',
  'batata palito',
  'batata assada',
  'batata frita',
  'batata-cozida',
  'batata batata',
];

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const automaticHtml = useMemo(() => {
    return foods.map((food, index) => (
      <>
        {/* {index % 2 === 0 && <div>} */}
        {index % 2 === 0 && <p>test</p>}
        <div>
          <p>{food}</p>
        </div>
        {/* {index % 2 !== 0 && </div>} */}
      </>
    ));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>Template</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        {automaticHtml}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
export default Dashboard;
```

Why, if I take the comments - `{/* {index % 2 === 0 && <div>} */}` and `{/* {index % 2 !== 0 && </div>} */}` out of the code, wouldn't work?

How can I fix it? I just want to insert **two elements of the array in a single div**.

Here is full [source code](https://github.com/MestreALMO/Testing_React).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a *new array* by iterating over the old array, e.g., using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const newFoods = foods.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if (index && (index + 1) % 2 === 0) {
    acc.push([foods[index - 1], foods[index]]);
  }
  return acc;
}, [] as Array<string[]>);
```

It will create a new array like:

```js
// old array
const foods = [
  'batata-palha',
  'batata palito',
  'batata assada',
  'batata frita',
  'batata-cozida',
  'batata batata',
];

// new formatted array
const newFoods = [
  [ "batata-palha", "batata palito" ],
  [ "batata assada", "batata frita" ],
  [ "batata-cozida", "batata batata" ]
]
```

Now, you can easily render it using a `map`:

```
const automaticHtml = useMemo(() => {
  return newFoods.map(item => (
    <div key={item.join()}>
      {item[0]}, {item[1]}
    </div>
  ));
}, []);
```